Semantics of volatile _Atomic
Generally _Atomic does not imply semantics of volatile, i.e. operations on the atomic object are not observable side effects that the compiler needs to preserve.
As a consequence the compiler can optimize e.g.
void f(_Atomic int* x) {
    atomic_fetch_add_explicit(x, 0, memory_order_relaxed);
}

to a no-op. And indeed Clang does perform this optimization, while GCC and MSVC do not.
I think it is expected that _Atomic and volatile semantics can be combined by combining the qualifiers, i.e. my expectation is that
void f(volatile _Atomic int* x) {
    atomic_fetch_add_explicit(x, 0, memory_order_relaxed);
}

forces the compiler to emit an instruction in f that implements a read-modify-write operation on x.
But interestingly Clang only behaves partially in the way I would expect it to. Clang emits:
f:
        mfence
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        ret

There is a load instruction, but no store to the memory. In particular this is not an atomic RMW.
While this may simply be a bug, I wonder what guarantees one should have on a volatile atomic RMW operation. Volatile access shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine, however "access" is defined in §3.1 of ISO C draft N3220 as:

<execution-time action> to read or modify the value of an object

which seemingly does not take into account an atomic RMW operation as an individual access.
Is the implementation supposed to guarantee that an atomic volatile RMW operation will result in both the equivalent of a volatile read and a volatile modification on the atomic object? And are they supposed to be guaranteed to be combined into one RMW access (in an implementation-defined manner) rather than an individual read and write? Or is all of this implementation-defined?

I posted an analogous question for C++ here, although there are other specification issue in the C++ case which that question focuses on.

I think a common-sense reading would suggest that atomic volatile would guarantee a full atomic RMW, even in the case where the read value is being written. Suppose there's a device at that address, and the proper driver operation is to read the register and write it back immediately with no possibility of some other access interleaved? How else would you code it? This is exactly the sort of optimization that volatile is supposed to prevent. This smells like a Clang bug.

Like with your C++ version of this question (Semantics of volatile std::atomic), I think this is a clang bug.  (And other comments there apply here).  For the same reason @StreveFord mentions, that volatile _Atomic * could be pointing at an MMIO register; that's one of the things volatile is for.  There might be a C/C++ difference in whether one could argue that this is compatible with the language of the standard or not, but it's enough of a quality-of-implementation / programmer-expectation problem that I'd consider it a bug regardless.

It's an age-old problem that standards orgs have wrestled with: whether to enshrine established practice as standard, especially if the established practice is not consistently implemented. My limited reading on the subject suggests that volatile has had different semantics across compilers and even versions of a compiler. It's hard to find a common core definition that prevents millions of lines of old code from breaking.

Here is, perhaps, a bit of circumstantial evidence supporting the "bug" theory. I changed your code to "*x = *x;" here and the assem definitely does write the value back, although not in an atomic RMW way. Interestingly, if you remove the _Atomic, the code changes slightly. (I could spend all day on godbolt.) Anyway, my point is that with "*x=*x" clang does do a read/write, and therefore conforms to the common interpretation of volatile.
